# ssh tunnel to a remote CUPS server

Tags: ssh, printing

There is a CUPS server beyond a firewall and I'd like to use it's printers. I have ssh access to computers that can access the CUPS server, and can get at the servers web interface by forwarding say port 1631. I cannot forward port 631 as I've not got root access to anything on the servers network.

In Ubuntu's 'Printing' control panel, I can enter the address of a server, but I've not been able to connect through the forwarded port (localhost:1631, which is forwarded to the remote CUPS server's 631 port).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet may be to treat the remote print spooler as a plain [IPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol) host and create local queues that forward to the remote printers.

Assuming you have created an `ssh` tunnel forwarding requests to the local port `1631` to the remote system's port `631`, try adding a new network print queue locally with the following device URI:

```
ipp://localhost:1631/printers/$remote_queue
```

Where `$remote_queue` is remote queue name.  If CUPS doesn't know about the remote printer model but it had been set up with an appropriate [PPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_Printer_Description) file, you can retrieve that PPD with the following command:

```
wget http://localhost:1631/printers/$remote_queue.ppd
```

After adding the local printer queue, click the `Change...` button next to `Make and Model` in the queue's properties window and follow the prompts to use the PPD.

Comment: This worked after the following change: use http instead of ipp. My PPD had a Cups filter, which I commented out on the client machine.